# C++ Toolbar and Statusbar layout overlap

Tags: c++, winapi, layout, toolbar, statusbar

I have created a toolbar that is located at the bottom of my application using the style flag `CCS_BOTTOM`. The problem is that I also have a status bar located at the bottom and when I use the style `CCS_BOTTOM` for my toolbar the two controls overlap each other.

I am trying to get the toolbar to be located directly above the status bar. Ive done a lot of research but cant figure anything out. Any ideas? I am using Win32.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> well I solved it by making a parent container. Not very efficient I suppose :D but it does get the job done